# Best way to monitor individual user activity on website

Tags: web-analytics

Most web analytic tools monitor user activity on a website but don't map it to a particular user. If my web application requires users to log in, is there a way I can track the progress of the logged in user as he/she goes through the web application?

So in a nutshell, this is something like Google Analytics. But instead of anonymous users, I want to map the browsing habits of someone to a user in my database. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a MySql DB with user activity functions that will be triggered as the user lands on different pages and executes different modules. with php you can also track ip address and log user activity on the server side.

```
function activity_track($user, $activity){
    $user = $user;
    $activity = $activity;
    $actIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    //write to db
}
```

then you can call this function anywhere like this:

```
activity_track("Me", "testing this sweet system");
```